# Amazon MTURK posting HITs to the Sandbox

Tags: r, mechanicalturk

So I am trying to post HITs from a csv file to the AWS sandbox and it prints only around 1190 of the rows out of 1460 every time. I have already cleaned out all external symbols from the file. For every (approximately) 300 HITs posted, this error appears several times then continues to post HITs from the csv file:

```
 Error (ServiceUnavailable):
```

`Service AWSMechanicalTurkRequester is currently unavailable. Please try again later
Request NA not valid for API request:
https://mechanicalturk.sandbox.amazonaws.com/?Service = AWSMechanicalTurkRequester
                                             &AWSAccessKeyId = REDACTED
                                             &RequesterAnnotation = Comment%20coding%20project%202016-07-12`

## This is the file I am using to create the HITs:

```
if (!(file.exists(input_file) && file.exists(template_file)))
  stop('File containing the template or the input values does not exist.')

# Read the input file
input_values <- read.csv(input_file, header = T);

 # Create or retrieve the HIT type.
  git_hit_type <- RegisterHITType(title = 'Categorize comments',
                            description = 'categorize comments!',
                            reward = '.05',
                            duration = seconds(minutes = 5),
                            keywords = 'categorization, coding,     moderation, category',
                            auto.approval.delay = seconds(days = 1),
                            qual.req = score_moder)


# Create the HITs and store their data.
created_hits <- BulkCreateFromTemplate(hit.type = git_hit_type$HITTypeId,
                                   template = template_file,
                                   input = input_values,
                                   expiration = seconds(days = 1),
                                   annotation = paste('Comment coding project', Sys.Date()))

# HITIDs of created HITs.
HITID_value <- rbindlist(created_hits)$HITId

# Clean up.
rm(input_file, template_file, input_values, created_hits)
```

Eventually, the code stops and freezes at around 1190 HITs posted. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there anything weird about the 1190/91 row? There's a chance you're running up against some kind of rate limiting with the MTurk API (the rates aren't documented, so it's pretty hard to know if you're hitting them).

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding! Yesterday it was printing 1190 rows pretty consistently but today, it appears its only printing around 580 rows in every test batch I run. Could it be something with AWS side of things for the sandbox (this server error has been occuring for weeks).

Comment: I suspect the sandbox has lower rate limits than the live server, so it could be that issue (if you've been moving back and forth between them).